# Compiling Errors Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I try to compile this code, I keep coming up with compiling errors. The code is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseballPitcher
{
    private final int MAX_GAMES = 15;
    private gamesPitched[];
    private int totalGames;
    private int totalRuns;
    private float totalInnings;
    private double ERA;

    public BaseballPitcher()
    {
        gamesPitched = new GamePitched[];
    }
    public void inputGameData()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        do
        {
            System.out.printf ("How many games will you enter (up to %d): ", MAX_GAMES);
            totalGames = input.nextInt();

            if (totalGames <= 0 || totalGames > MAX_GAMES)
            {
                System.out.printf ("Error: You may only enter up to %d games" + " - Please try again\n\n", MAX_GAMES);
            }
         } while (totalGames <= 0 || totalGames > MAX_GAMES);

         for (int x = 0, x < totalGames, x++)
         {
             gamesPitched[x] = new GamePitched();
             gamesPitched[x].inputGame();
         }
    }
}
```

The compile errors I am receiving are:

```
[Please list your compile error or errors].
```

Why am I getting the compile errors?

Comment: Why would you tell us you get errors but not tell us what they are? It seems like you just want us to fix it without you making any effort.

Comment: How can you ask to limit how many changes need to be applied to have working code...

Answer (score 4):

It appears you have a custom class named `GamePitched`. Your array `gamesPitched[]` is likely supposed to be an array of this type, yet you have declared it without a type. Try `private GamePitched[] gamesPitched;`

Your loop just has syntax errors -- the `,` should be `;`, which Java uses to separate the clauses in a for loop.

You should read the errors provided in the stacktrace. Even if you are new to Java, they are fairly descriptive and would help you identify where the problems exist (and often suggest the fix).

Comment: Actually, I was able to figure it out from there. My main problem was just the array. Thank you everyone for the suggestion. Sorry for the sloppiness of this question, this is my first time using this site.

Comment: One more change is required to get this to work.  You'll need `gamesPitched = new GamePitched[totalGames];` between the `do-while` loop and the `for` loop, otherwise there won't be space for anything in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how it should like, I guess

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseballPitcher
{
    private final int MAX_GAMES = 15;
    private GamePitched[] gamesPitched;
    private int totalGames;
    private int totalRuns;
    private float totalInnings;
    private double ERA;

    public BaseballPitcher()
    {
        gamesPitched = new GamePitched[10];
    }
    public void inputGameData()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        do
        {
            System.out.printf ("How many games will you enter (up to %d): ", MAX_GAMES);
            totalGames = input.nextInt();

            if (totalGames <= 0 || totalGames > MAX_GAMES)
            {
                System.out.printf ("Error: You may only enter up to %d games" + " - Please try again\n\n", MAX_GAMES);
            }
         } while (totalGames <= 0 || totalGames > MAX_GAMES);

         for (int x = 0; x < totalGames; x++)
         {
             gamesPitched[x] = new GamePitched();
             gamesPitched[x].inputGame();
         }
    }
}
```

at least to compile. Cannot say anything about the logic

and the other class must have at least this method

```
public class GamePitched {

    public void inputGame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```